# How to select same column from a table with diferent ids

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Table tbl_seguimiento.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VSZ5.png

Table tbl_usuario.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2alH.png

I have to select multiple values according stored ids on both tables. The thing is have to select same column twice but with a different id.

I tried using left join statement.

This was my first attempt:

```
SELECT t1.n_caso, t2.nombre, t5.nombre, t1.inspector, t1.estado, 
t1.detalle, t2.nombre, t1.fecha_ingreso, 
t1.fecha_regreso_inspeccion,t1.fecha_aprobacion, t1.fecha_entrega, 
t1.modificado FROM tbl_seguimiento t1, tbl_departamento t5, tbl_usuario t2 
WHERE t1.funcionario = t2.id_usuario 
AND t1.departamento = t5.id_departamento AND t2.id_usuario =  
t1.delegado_por;
```

Then I tried this:

```
 SELECT t1.n_caso, t2.nombre, t5.nombre, t1.inspector, t1.estado,    t1.detalle, t2.nombre, t1.fecha_ingreso, t1.fecha_regreso_inspeccion,
    t1.fecha_aprobacion, t1.fecha_entrega, t1.modificado FROM tbl_seguimiento 
    t1, tbl_departamento t5, tbl_usuario t2
    LEFT JOIN tbl_seguimiento t7 ON t7.delegado_por = t2.id_usuario
    WHERE t1.funcionario = t2.id_usuario AND t1.departamento = t5.id_departamento;
```

I want to select the value nombre from tbl_usuario twice according ids on both tables. The ids columns are delegado_por and id_usuario.

Comment: did you try inner join query

Comment: You need to join tbl_usuario twice with different ids

Comment: Thank you for your advice @Strawberry I will take that in consideration next time. Thank you for your help folks.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### USE UNION:

let's say we have this table:

[image]

```
SELECT id, name FROM test.user 
WHERE id between 1 and 3
UNION 
SELECT id, name FROM test.user 
WHERE id between 5 and 6
```

Comment: Why is this better than not using a UNION?

Answer (score 0):

**USING INNER JOIN:**

This way you just have to change the t reference on the select statement.

```
SELECT t1.n_caso, t3.nombre, t5.nombre, t1.inspector, t1.estado, t1.detalle, t2.nombre, t1.fecha_ingreso, t1.fecha_regreso_inspeccion,
t1.fecha_aprobacion, t1.fecha_entrega, t1.modificado
FROM tbl_departamento t5, tbl_seguimiento t1
INNER JOIN tbl_usuario t2 ON t1.delegado_por = t2.id_usuario
INNER JOIN tbl_usuario t3 ON t2.id_usuario = t2.id_usuario
WHERE t1.funcionario = t3.id_usuario AND t1.departamento = t5.id_departamento;
```

Comment: `ON t2.id_usuario = t2.id_usuario`
?!?!?!?!